# Regarding invertibility and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have hard time understanding basis and invertibility.

1. If I want to find basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (Euclidean space), the number of vectors in $\text{span}\{v_1, ..., v_n\} = V$ (vector space) can be less than $n$? I thought that the vector $(1, 1)'$ satisfies the two conditions (spanning, linearly independence) to be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it right?
2. Regarding the invertibility, I learned that if rank is the full rank, the inverse exists. In other words, if $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix and the $\text{rank}(A) = n$, the inverse exists. Then, only the inverse exist in case if the basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $n$ vectors, and not exists on $(1, 1)'$ example?

Comment: A basis is a linearly independent spanning set. Note that $(1, 1)$ does not span the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so it alone cannot be a basis for the space.

Comment: $(1,1)'$ just spans a line in $R^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1.$ Vector $(1,1)$ satisfies the condition of linear independence, but not of spanning. For a basis you need a set that spans across the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example with $(1,1)$, you can only represent vectors of the form $(a,a)$ and not $(a,b)$, where $a\ne b$. This could be a basis of subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not of space $\mathbb{R}^2$. In the specific case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ the canonical basis is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, but your basis could also consist of any two linearly independent vectors. Generally if $dim V=n$, then your basis should be of size $n$, meaning it should span $n$ linearly independent vectors.

$2.$ You would be correct. This touches the topic of linear transformations, so check that out. In practice you'll see that if you use something like [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), which is the most common method of finding an inverse, if $rank A<n$ you'll end up with $n-rankA$ rows of zeros. That would show you that there is no inverse of $A$.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot. So you are saying that generally basis for R^n has n independent vectors? Is there any exception examples?

Comment: @katie as far as I know there are none.